# Rails show total of nested values in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a feature in my app to create purchase orders. I have classic tables purchase_orders and purchase_order_lists.

purchase_order has many purchase_order_lists and purchase_order_lists belongs_to purchase_order. Foreign key is on purchase_orders table, column PURCHASE_ORDER. Database table names are capital.

In my `purchase_orders` controller I have:

```
  def show
        @purchase_order = PurchaseOrder.find(params[:ID])
        @purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.find(params[:ID])
    end
```

In my model purchase_oder_list.rb

```
def total
        (self.UNITS * self.PRICEBUY)
end
```

In my view `purchase_orders/show`

```
 <td><%= purchase_order_list.total %></td>
```

which return the correct value for each purchase order list row.

Then in the same view to show the total:

```
@purchase_order_list.to_a.sum(&:total)
```

which should show the total of method `total` but it raises the error

```
Couldn't find PurchaseOrderList with 'ID'=POID-00001
```

as it is looking for a Purchase Order ID among Purchase Order List IDs.

How can I fix it to return the sum of method `total`for a certain purchase order?

Comment: `@purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.find(params[:ID])` looks like no meaning here. If I really understood your question Just remove it from controller.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. I have edited the question. I added it in controller to be able to calculate the total of purchase_order_list method `total` for a certain purchase order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `find` while there are many purchase_order_lists for one purchase order.

To fix I used `where` instead:

```
@purchase_order_list = PurchaseOrderList.where(PURCHASE_ORDER: params[:ID])
```